# iPad app -- long black screen before viewDidLoad fires

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

we are relatively inexperienced with iOS programming, but we're getting there.  We're getting to the point where we are fine tuning, and in our current ipad app under development, we notice that when we launch the app there is about a full second of black screen (ie after the icon zooms to occupy the screen) before our screen appears.  In debugging mode, I see that this is happening before my main controller viewDidLoad event... which I think is my first opportunity to programmatically make anything visible.

Is this a common issue, or is there any way to avoid or lessen this?  I don't notice this in other apps we've downloaded from the App store.  We do have a medium amount of resources, I'm not sure if this slows it down or if there is anything we should be doing to precompile/preload resources.  Or if I had any control over this (pre-viewDidLoad) I could throw up a splash screen, that would look better than a black screen at least.

Basically I'm looking for any pointers or pro tips :)  Thank you.

Comment: Have you added a launch screen? This should show immediately on start and will show until your app shows its own content. You have to add launch images for each resolution and aspect ration to the Images.xcassets -> LaunchImage area in the project navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's supposed to be your launch image.

Your splash screen is supposed to go there. If you have not provided an image for a splash, it defaults to black.

From the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)

> The placeholder image gives users the impression that your app is fast
>   and responsive because it appears instantly and is quickly replaced by
>   the first screen of your app. Every app must supply a launch file or
>   at least one static image.

Answer (score 0):

As Rory said - launch images. Although if you are targeting iOS 8 you could alternatively use a Storyboard file for your launch image to avoid having to define multiple resolutions. See [this Apple Doc Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html).